# How to return a value from a do while loop

Tags: java, loops, return, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game that requires a valid input from the user before continuing. How I was trying to tackle this was by making a do while loop and an if else statement inside to verify the input. If it is anything other than the choices given, then the condition stays false and the program loops. However I was trying to figure out how to return the correct value that the user inputs which gets stored in UserChoice so I can access the variable outside of the loop and continue on with the program.

Here is my code:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter in rock, paper or scissors:");
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    String UserChoice = user.nextLine(); 

    if(!UserChoice.equals("rock") && (!UserChoice.equals("paper")) && (!UserChoice.equals("scissors"))){
        System.out.println("You must enter either rock, paper or scissors. Try again: ");
    }else{
        isRight = true;
    }
}while(isRight==false);
```

Comment: declare a variable outside the loop, and store it in that variable

Comment: prefer `while(!isRight)`

Answer (score 1):

Just move the variable declaration out of the loop, to make it available out of the scope of the do-while block, just like:

```
String userChoice = null;
do{
    System.out.println("Enter in rock, paper or scissors:");
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    userChoice = user.nextLine(); 

    if(!"rock".equals(userChoice) && (!"paper".equals(userChoice)) && (!"scissors".equals(userChoice))){
         System.out.println("You must enter either rock, paper or scissors. Try again: ");
    }else{
         isRight = true;
    }

}while(isRight==false);

//here you can still use it
System.out.println(userChoice);
```

You can read about variable scopes for example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

And just some remarks. It's preffered to use `"rock".equals(userChoice)` notation while calling `equals`, in order to prevent NullPointerException if your `userChoice` object will be NULL, for any reason. Furthermore, you can move this line `Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);` out of the loop. No reason to create new instance of the scanner on every iteration. And the last one, while condition `isRight==false` could be substituted with `!isRight`, no need to compare it to something, since the variable is boolean itself.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `UserChoice` before the do while.

```
String UserChoice = "";

do 
....

while ();

System.out.println(UserChoice);
```

Answer (score 1):

Next to declaring the variable outside of the loop (as I suggested in the comments earlier) a few remarks about your code:

```
                System.out.println("Enter in rock, paper or scissors:");
                Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
                String userChoice = user.nextLine(); //stick to naming conventions, it makes your code easier to read



                while(!userChoice.equals("rock") && (!userChoice.equals("paper")) && (!userChoice.equals("scissors"))){
                    System.out.println("You must enter either rock, paper or scissors. Try again: ");
            System.out.println("Enter in rock, paper or scissors:");
                 userChoice = user.nextLine(); //stick to naming 
            }
```

There is no need at all to loop that entire block of code each time. All that needs to be repeated, is the error message and reading new value for userChoice, and that only if the original entry was invalid.

In your code, for instance, you are creating a new instance of Scanner each time you loop, while you could just reuse the existing one.